# How can I properly position the arrows in my jQuery navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a horizontal navigation menu with vertical dropdowns using CSS and jQuery.  I would like to add an arrow to all top-level links that have sub-menus to indicate that they have sub-menus.  My problem right now is that the arrows are positioned below the link text.  I would like the arrows to be to the right of the link text.  Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfqy5cku/) to demonstrate the problem.

My CSS:

```
nav {
    background: url(../img/navigationBackground.gif) repeat-x #e2e3df;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2d3132;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    box-shadow:         4px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 1px solid #484947;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e6e3;
    height: 55px;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #2d3132;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    height: 55px;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #2E3233;
    color: #E2E3DF;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid #2E3233;
    box-shadow:         4px 4px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: #fffefc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E3233;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #2e3233;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Personal</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Tips &amp; Tricks</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Web Designs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Development Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Photo Gallery</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My jQuery

```
$(function(){
    //Find all ul elements within items in the nav
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function(){
        //Prevent the links that have submenus from being clicked
        $(this).children('a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        })
        .append('<div class="arrow-down"></div>');
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            console.log('hovered');
            $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'inline');
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your .arrow-down class

```
.arrow-down {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

If you want, you could add additional margin (e.g. `margin-left: 10px;`) to position it with a gap

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5sy2kmt8/

---

With the margin and the above fix it looks like this (image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the arrow icon.

Setting outer relative to the inner absolute container will achieve it.

**Changes:**

Added `position: relative;` to `nav ul li a`.

Added `position: absolute; top: 24px; right: 0;` to `.arrow-down`.

Adjust `top` / `right` properties if required.

Have updated the css code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfqy5cku/2/)